# How does "thou" equal "oneg"?

Tags: crossword-clues

While doing a crossword today, I came across the clue "Thou".  The correct answer ended up being "oneg".  I can't make heads or tails of this, no matter how I parse it.  How does "thou" relate to "oneg"?

Things I considered/tried:

- oneg - whole word. Googled this and only came up with a Jewish word meaning "delight"
- o-neg - blood type.  Don't see any connection to "thou"
- on eg - I got nothing for this
- one g - one gram, one god, one G (as in G-force)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You were on the right track:

> A "thou" is slang for "thousand" (see [M-W, as a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thou)), often in the sense of dollars. Similarly, "G" is slang for $1000 (see again [M-W, noun sense 6](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/g)). Therefore, a thou would be equivalent to one G.

Comment: Damn.  If they had said "a thou", I'd have gotten it.  Upvoted and will accept if no one posts anything better today

Comment: This clue brought to you by the demise of Þ and Ð from the English alphabet :)

Comment: @chepner Not familiar with those, but I'm guessing they represent the slightly different "th" sounds I spent about a minute and a half making after I read this answer

Comment: They were present in Old English, prior to the Norman invasion. (I think they were both used interchangeably for either sound, though.) Modern Icelandic uses  Þ for the unvoiced version, though  Ð be either voiced or unvoiced depending on context. A less drastic reform proposal I like is to use "th" for the unvoiced sound, "dh" for the voiced sound (just as "t" is unvoiced and "d" is unvoiced).

Comment: Or just use the IPA symbols, theta (voiceless) and eth (voiced). But that's more of a pronunciation key than a spelling reform.

Comment: @chepner Þ can also be voiced depending on context (e.g., _er það..?_ ‘is it..?' is generally [εɾða] in regular speech). Unlike in English, the two sounds are allophones of the same phoneme /θ/ in Icelandic, written _þ_ word-initially and _ð_ elsewhere (except in a few Greek loanwords where [θ] appears internally, like _Aþena_ ‘Athena’). But iconically _þ_ does represent the unvoiced version and _ð_ the voiced one.